# MySQL: SQL Query to return Date from Date/Timestamp Column

Tags: mysql, sql, string

In a table I have a stored string column "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS" and I'm looking for a query to return just the "MM/DD/YYYY" part.

Any ideas?

Comment: @user693121 - Is this MS Sql Server?

Comment: Yes. And it turns out this is a DATETIME field NOT a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the column type is `char` or `varchar`, then

`SELECT LEFT(colname, 10)`

will suffice. 
If it's a `datetime` type, then try

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colname , "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name :(

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` is indeed a MySQL function. You must have added an extra quote or something.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT is not compatible with Microsoft SQL 2005. Trying to use a variation of "CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column, 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]" but VARCHAR and CHAR are not recognized either.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a MySQL DATETIME field instead of a string field, really. That would allow you to apply date and time functions, which help tremendously when dealing with temporal data.

In your case, since your data is a string type, and not in MySQL Isodate format (YYYY-MM-DD), you can work only using string functions like SUBSTRING() and specialisations thereof (LEFT, ...).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
Date and Time functions overview

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html
String functions

Comment: Turns out they are DATETIME fields. What would I apply?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use substring !!!

SELECT SUBSTRING(TimeStamp,7,10);

Answer (score 0):

if it is a string use [SUBSRT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) or [LEFT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left) to extract required part, however it would be wise to have it stored as datatime type